# Xamarin Forms: CollectionView is not working in ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

I am using `CollectionView` for the horizontal listview. It is working fine in android but in ios, the items are showing on one top of another. Attaching a screenshot below:

[image]

**XAML**

```
<CollectionView 
             HeightRequest="30"
             SelectionMode="Single"
             SelectionChanged="ItemTapped"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             x:Name="collectionview"
             ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">
             <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                          <StackLayout Margin="5">
                                  <Label
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       FontSize="Large"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding title}"/>
                             </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                 </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
          </CollectionView>
```

Xaml.cs

```
public async void ItemTapped(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as MyModel);
            if (selectedItem != null)
            {
                //Do action
            }
        }
```

Add below code in AppDelegate class on iOS and MainActivity class on Android, before calling Forms.Init:

```
Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
```

Am I missing something in IOS?

Comment: Your code works fine on my side . What's the parent view of the CollectionView ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Stacklayout

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Uploaded my XAML file on drive. Drive link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eTRPwq1jEDZem0xyjOmPiN3Fd1g5dUU6 Can you please check?

Comment: Your sample looks very complicated(and contains some third library control) . You could create a sample which contains the issue . The codes which you post on the question work fine , so I think maybe the issue caused by other codes.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I will provide you a sample.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Created a sample, can you please check.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11e9DOUwJ52VmdnfBjUwi7_Hj8lxVxxjY

Comment: It works fine on my side , I used static data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203321/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems an existing issue of Xamarin.Forms . As workaround you can update the version of Xamarin.Forms to 4.4 pre2 .

[image]

And you can check the Xamarin.forms [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.4/4.4.0-pre2) .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add a LinearItemsLayout which would give you some control over how these items look:

```
 <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>  
 <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal" />
 </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
```

Let me know in case if you face any issues!

Comment: What version of XF do you have?

Comment: My XF version is 4.3

Comment: Then you need to clean and build because this works for me