# Xamarin Forms: How to change the background color of selected item in flowlistview?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, background-color

I am using `flowlistview` for showing items in UI. When taps on an item in the `flowlistview`, I need to change the background color or highlight the selected item. I tried `FlowTappedBackgroundColor` and `FlowRowBackgroundColor` properties of `flowlistview`. But it is not working as expected. I go through this [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-change-listview-selecteditem-bg-color-in-xamarin-forms/), but this works only for the normal listview. How can I do this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source code of the **FlowViewCell** , you will find that the super-class of FlowViewCell is not **ViewCell** ,but **ContentView** . So it won't work if you follow the blog.

```
namespace DLToolkit.Forms.Controls
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     FlowListView content view cell.
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class FlowViewCell : ContentView, IFlowViewCell
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowViewCell class.
        public FlowViewCell();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Raised when cell is tapped.
        public virtual void OnTapped();
    }
}
```

Create binding on the Background of the control inside FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate , change in FlowItemTappedCommand .

#### code behind

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged 
 {
    public string Title
    {
        get;set;
    }


    private Color bgColor;
    public Color BGColor
    {
        set { 
        if(value != null)
            {
                bgColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return bgColor;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> List { set; get; }

    public ICommand ItemTappedCommand { get; set; }


   public ViewModel()
    {
        List = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        List.Add(new Model() { Title = "1" ,BGColor = Color.White });
        List.Add(new Model() { Title = "2" , BGColor = Color.White });
        List.Add(new Model() { Title = "3", BGColor = Color.White });
        List.Add(new Model() { Title = "4", BGColor = Color.White });

        ItemTappedCommand = new Command((obj)=> {

            //reset the bg color 
            foreach(var model in List)
            {
                model.BGColor = Color.White;
            }

            Model mo = obj as Model;
            int index = List.IndexOf(mo);           
            mo.BGColor = Color.Red;

        });
    }
} 

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

#### in xaml

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" 
                  SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="false"
                  FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}"
                  FlowItemsSource="{Binding List}"   >

    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> 
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                   BackgroundColor="{Binding BGColor}"
                   VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                   XAlign="Center" 
                   YAlign="Center" 
                   Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

</flv:FlowListView>
```

In addition, **CollectionView** is available after XF 4.3. You can use it instead of the third-party library . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction .

Comment: If I select multiple items all items have red background color. I need background color only for the last selected item.

Comment: Please update the collectionview answer on my thread, it is working fine in ios now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103182/xamarin-forms-collectionview-is-not-working-in-ios

Comment: What is the cause of the issue?

Comment: For the current thread: Added all the codes, but getting 2 errors in error list.https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LL1gE-peGeAL2F4iUjDIuBJ0q0PlnME8

Comment: Make sure that all versions of nuget package and XF are up to date .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203470/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-lucas-zhang-msft).